# Find Maclaurin series of sin(x) from e^x

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

So I managed to find the expression of $\cos(x)$ by using $\cos(x) = \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$ and then $e^x = \sum ^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ and using the change of variable n=2m. However, when I try something similar with $\sin(x)$, i can't seem to get anywhere. So how do I do this?

Comment: Are you not allowed to argue that $sinx=(-cosx)'$ and then apply the results you have obtained for $cosx$?

Comment: The sine works very similarly. All terms of even degree will cancel out and you are left with $i$ times an alternating series with odd degrees. By the way, it is weird that you could not achieve that if you managed the cosine.

Comment: Oh that's a nice trick! I should have thought of that, I got the right summation formula now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have\begin{align}\require{cancel}\sin(x)&=\frac1{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})\\&=\frac1{2i}\left(\left(\cancel1+ix-\cancel{\frac{x^2}{2!}}-\frac{x^3}{3!}i+\cancel{\frac{x^4}{4!}}+\cdots\right)\right.-\\&{}\quad-\left.\left(\cancel1-ix-\cancel{\frac{x^2}{2!}}+\frac{x^3}{3!}i+\cancel{\frac{x^4}{4!}}+\cdots\right)\right)\\&=\frac1{\cancel2\bcancel i}\left(\cancel2\bcancel ix-\cancel2\frac{x^3}{3!}\bcancel i+\cdots\right)\\&=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots\end{align}

Comment: Sir  but $\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ was derived by Euler via the series expansion of cosine and sine right??

Comment: Yes, that's how Euler did it. But we also can *define* $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{)2n+1)!}z^{2n+1}$ and as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}z^{2n}$. And there are other possible definitions.

Comment: @RAHUL The OP starts from $\cos x = \frac 12 (e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$ and just asks for a similar way of dealing with $\sin x$. So, the use of this formula is quite  adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Just note that
$$
\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i} = \sin x
$$

So, you have that
$$
\sin x = \frac{1}{2i} \left(\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{(ix)^n}{n!}-\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{(-ix)^n}{bn!} \right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

As $\;\sin x=\dfrac{\mathrm e^{ix}-\mathrm e^{-ix}}{2i}$, it is the *imaginary part* in the expansion of $\mathrm e^{ix}$.

For instance, computing the first 6 terms of this expansion:
$$\mathrm e^{ix}=1+ix-\frac{x^2}{2!} -\frac{ix^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{ix^5}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\dots,$$
one obtains
$$\sin x =x -\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\dots$$

*Added*: it is easy to show in full generality that there there are only alternating odd power terms since
$$ i^n=\begin{cases}\phantom{-}1&\text{if}\quad n\equiv 0\mod4, \\
-1&\text{if}\quad n\equiv 2\mod4, \\ \phantom{-}i &\text{if}\quad n\equiv 1\mod4,\\ -i &\text{if}\quad n\equiv 3\mod4.  \end{cases} $$

*Another method*: You can determine directly Maclaurin's formula using  that $\sin'(x)=\sin\bigl(x+\frac\pi 2\bigr)$, whence
$$\sin^{(n)}x=\sin\Bigl(x+n\frac\pi2\Bigr).$$

Comment: @PierreCarre; First, probably we were writing our answers more or less simultaneously. Second, there's a small difference : it is  slightly simpler to calculate,  since I expand  only $\mathrm e^{ix}$ and extract its imaginary part. This being said, I don't think there can be fundamentally different answers for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from $$e^{ix}=\cos x + i\sin x$$ and
$$
e^{x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

So
\begin{align}
\sin x 
&= \mathbb{Im}\{e^{ix}\}\\
&= \mathbb{Im}\bigg\{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(ix)^k}{k!}\bigg\}\\
&= \mathbb{Im}\bigg\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^{j-1}\frac{x^{2j}}{(2j)!}+i\sum_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^{j-1}\frac{x^{2j-1}}{(2j-1)!}\bigg\}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^{j-1}\frac{x^{2j-1}}{(2j-1)!}\\
&= \frac{x^1}{1!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots
\end{align}